# Linux C forbid coredumps only for my program

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, coredump, systems-programming

Is it possible to forbid creation of coredumps only for my program? I know that it's possible to change behaviour for entire system using `ulimit`, but I'd like to block it only for my program. What should I code in my program? Maybe write some kernel module?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing this.  Whether core dumps should be allowed is a policy question that should be decided by the user running the program and / or by the system administrator.  Programs generally ought not to try to take such things into their own hands.

Comment: In following @JohnBollinger's comment, one could create a no-dump user (or group), chown that binary to be owned by that user, and set the SUID bit on it so the program runs as said user, and restrict core-dumps for that user in limits.conf.  That way it is something configurable by the system administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Call `setrlimit()` to do the same thing that the `ulimit` command does.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rlimit new;
new.rlim_cur = new.rlim_max = 0;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &new);
```